# How to remove inner faces generated by union boolean modifier?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, faces

I know it is possible to select by trait interior faces and remove them, but when I am using modifiers, without applying I would not be able to do so, is there any way to clean the mess union modifier generate?

[image]
Sample: [puzzle.blend](https://mega.nz/file/Gd8BxAaD#gz-3srbiIBfpBpz2TPWxiDuNhfutytuRWSSvF_KzobU)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is new boolean algorithm in blender, so use the exact option in the boolean modifier if you are in b3d 2.91 to remove that overlapping geometry, but in 2.83-2.9 or older you have to remove those faces manually after applying the modifier...

Comment: I was using 2.83.5, I updated to 2.90.1 now but still there wasn't any fix, today 2.91 is beta, then I tried it and there was, fixed!